# How can you send structured-data to syslog from Twisted?

Tags: twisted, syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to send structured-data as defined in [RFC5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424) to syslog from Twisted.
I'm on Ubuntu and the syslog implementation is rsyslog.

I'm running the twisted app with '`twistd --syslog`', which sends messages sent with log.msg and log.err to syslog.

So far I have been trying to format the message in log.msg according to the spec, like this e.g.:

```
log.err('[exampleSDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"]')
```

But that does not work. Rsyslog just displays it as a regular message.
Does anybody know how to do this?
Should I look at a different logging library maybe?

Comment: Do you have an example of code that successfully sends "structured-data" to syslog using the Python stdlib `syslog` module?  If you could demonstrate that working, it would be a good clue that the problem lies in Twisted's syslog integration.  If not, then it's a clue the problem is in Python's syslog module.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone It seems that the problem is with Python's syslog module since I was also unable to send structured-data with it. I suspect it is based on the older [RFC 3164](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3164) instead of [RFC 5424](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424).

Comment: @rkrzr It may be appropriate to edit the question (adding extra information about the problem you're having now) or provide your own answer if you feel it's solved.

Comment: @thepaul ok, I answered the question myself now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the problem has nothing to do with Twisted's syslog integration but rather that Python's stdlib syslog module does not support the logging format described in RFC 5424.

Furthermore RFC 5424 seems to be  [Dead On Arrival](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/rsyslog/users/6361) (at least the structured data part). It will most likely be replaced by the syntax described in [Project lumberjack](https://fedorahosted.org/lumberjack/) which is based on either JSON or XML.
So if you are interested in more structured logging you should probably take a look at that.

To format messages according to that standard one can use a custom formatter that conforms to the standard, like the one given [here](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2012/03/structured-logging.html).